# Error in insert_chapter_script(config, "before") when building all formats

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

After installing the minimal bookdown example I got the following error when I try to build all formats of the book:

```
==> rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')

Error in insert_chapter_script(config, "before") : 
  object 'config' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> insert_code_chunk -> insert_chapter_script
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

But building the formats separately (pdf_book, epub_book and gitbook) does work.

I installed the minimum bookdown example via RStudio-> New Project… -> New Directory -> Book Project using bookdown.

I use the new RStudio preview version 1.1.383, bookdown 0.5.3. and rmarkdown 1.6.0.9004. (I believe it did work with the previous RStudio version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the current development version of **bookdown**. I just [fixed it](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/7314842e4f8ef30db9548c6a6bc87bfd86b53d48) on Github. Please `devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')`. Thanks!